# How can I checkout my Shopify order using API?

Tags: php, shopify

I am using Shopify API to create products and orders. But I can't find a way to checkout my order through api call.

```
    $request = new CURLCall();
    $line_items = array("line_items" =>
        array(array(
                "variant_id" => 123456789,
                "quantity" => 5))
    );
    $data = json_encode(array("checkout" => $line_items));
    $url = "https://{API_KEY}:{Password}@shop.myshopify.com/admin/checkouts.json";

    // Initialize CURL for PHP
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
        'Accept: application/json')
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($response);
```

Code above returns this message,

{"errors":"Not Found"}

Thank you.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/response-status-codes

Comment: thanks for this, I got 404. Thanks for this @AnkitShah

Comment: URL Have some Issue Sure

Comment: I'm using the same url format for other requests and it's all doing good.

Comment: May be firewall. Can check with Proxy?

Comment: Nope, no issue with that at all.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you cannot checkout an order with the API. Secondly, you can read the abandoned checkouts with your call to the checkouts endpoint.

If you want to actually cash in an order you create, you would want to create a transaction for the order, not a checkout. You can create capture transactions for example. You can never actually transact money this way though... your customer has to enter their credit card details to turn API created orders into real ones.